# Calculate missing coordinate

Tags: javascript, html, math, canvas, geometry

I am about to develop a special animation with a canvas. I want to rotate an isosceles triangle around a circle.

[image: img]

**Note**: I do not want to rotate the canvas itself. I'd like to calculate the 3 points of the triangle every single frame. `(!)`.

---

```js
let canvas = document.getElementById("canvas")
let ctx = canvas.getContext("2d")

let trianglePositionAngle = 0;
let triangleSizeAngle = 15;


function draw(trianglePositionAngle) {
  ctx.fillStyle = "blue"
  ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height)

  let radius = 70
  ctx.fillStyle = "black"
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(canvas.width / 2, canvas.height / 2, radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
  ctx.fill();

  let triangle = {
    x1: canvas.width / 2 + radius * Math.cos((trianglePositionAngle * Math.PI / 180)),
    y1: canvas.height / 2 + radius * Math.sin((trianglePositionAngle * Math.PI / 180)),

    x2: canvas.width / 2 + radius * Math.cos(((trianglePositionAngle + triangleSizeAngle) * Math.PI / 180)),
    y2: canvas.height / 2 + radius * Math.sin(((trianglePositionAngle + triangleSizeAngle) * Math.PI / 180))
  }

  ctx.fillStyle = "red"
  ctx.beginPath()
  ctx.moveTo(triangle.x1, triangle.y1);
  ctx.lineTo(triangle.x2, triangle.y2);
  ctx.lineTo(canvas.width/2, canvas.height/2); // looking for the coordinates of this point
  ctx.fill();
}

setInterval(function() {
  draw(trianglePositionAngle++)
},100)
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="200" height="200"></canvas>
```

---

Since I know that the opposite sides of the triangle are of equal length, I only have to calculate the last point. I know the theoretical path:

- Calculate gradient A of distance xy1/xy2
- Calculate the center M of distance xy1/xy2
- normally from A with a certain length (e.g. 20px) from the center M calculate

Nevertheless I have problems to implement it and hope that someone will help me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To calculate coordinates of the third point of triangle, you should use middle angle betweeen points 1 and 2. And radius should be enlarged by the height of triangle. I gave simple approximation for the last parameter:

```
x3: canvas.width / 2 + 
   radius * (1 + 0.866 * triangleSizeAngle * Math.PI / 180) * 
   Math.cos(((trianglePositionAngle + triangleSizeAngle / 2) * Math.PI / 180))

y3: canvas.height / 2 + 
   radius * (1 + 0.866 * triangleSizeAngle * Math.PI / 180) * 
   Math.sin(((trianglePositionAngle + triangleSizeAngle / 2) * Math.PI / 180))
```

`0.866=Sqrt(3)/2` is ratio of isosceles triangle height and edge.

Approximation uses arc length as edge (they are slightly different, but it is negligible for drawing purposes).

More precise value

```
instead of 
  (1 + 0.866 * triangleSizeAngle * Math.PI / 180)
you can use
  (cos(0.5* triangleSizeAngle * Math.PI / 180) + 
  Sqrt(3)* sin(0.5* triangleSizeAngle * Math.PI / 180))
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't really understand your answer. Where does the 0.866 come from and where is the y3? Why is there a comma at the end? And why do I need an `approximation` if I'm able to calculate the exact value? Huh? `:)`

Comment: I've added some explanation. I hoped that it is apparent that y-coordinate uses same parameters but `sin` instead of `cos`

Comment: Also added precise value for radius enlargement